# C# out parameter for delegate not maintaining value

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates, ref, out

I have a function which takes a custom delegate as parameter in order to achieve the following:

```
delegate T TryParseDelegate<I,O,T>(I input, O output);

private string[] ReadMultiStringValue (string propertyName, TryParseDelegate<string, string[], bool> tryParse)
{
  string cellValue = GetCellValue(propertyName);
  string[] values = null;

  if (tryParse(cellValue, values))
    return values;
  else
    throw new Exception("Invalid cell value");
}
```

Which I would call like so:

```
string[] parsedValue = ReadMultiStringValue("myProperty", (n,p) => ParseHelper.TryParseName(n, out p));
```

When I debug the code, everything seems to work properly, except "values" remains null after going through tryParse (and yet is updated correctly when inside the TryParseName method). I tried adding the out keyword to values, but I get the error "Argument 2 may not be passed with the out keyword".

What am I missing here?

Comment: Yeah, try `public delegate T TryParseDelegate<I, O, T>(I input, out O output);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the output parameter to `out` parameter and pass it like so:

```
delegate T TryParseDelegate<I,O,T>(I input, out O output);


if (tryParse(cellValue, out values))
```

The reason why it doesn't work without `out` is, when you pass values the reference is copied then you pass that reference as `out` to `TryParseName` method. But it doesn't change the original `values`.

It's similar to doing this:

```
string x = "foo";
string y = x;
x = "bar"; // this won't change the y.
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried adding the out keyword to values, but I get the error "Argument 2 may not be passed with the out keyword"

This is because you need to change the delegate first.

```
delegate T TryParseDelegate<I, O, T>(I input, out O output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined your delegate with an `out` parameter. Change it to this:

```
delegate T TryParseDelegate<I, O, T>(I input, out O output);
                                            //^^^ Add this
```

And call it like this:

```
if (tryParse(cellValue, out values))
```